# PIC16F1787 I2C read temperature from TCN75S: ACKEN bit doesn't get cleared

Tags: c, temperature

I'm trying to read the temperature from a TCN75S sensor using a PIC.

```
i2c_start();
i2c_write(0b10010000);
i2c_write(0x00);
i2c_stop();

i2c_start();
i2c_write(0b10010001);
PORTD = i2c_read();
i2c_stop();
```

First I set the register pointer to the temperature register and then I try to read the temperature from the register, but I get stuck in a while loop, because the ACKEN bit from the SSPCON2 register doesn't get cleared.

read function:

```
char i2c_read(void)
{
    char data = 0x00;
    i2c_wait();
    SSPCON2bits.RCEN = 1;
    i2c_wait();
    data = SSPBUF;
    i2c_wait();
    SSPCON2bits.ACKDT = 0;
    SSPCON2bits.ACKEN = 1;
    return data;
}
```

wait function:

```
void i2c_wait(void)
{
    while((SSPSTAT & 0x04) || (SSPCON2 & 0x1F))
    {
        PORTD = SSPCON2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic of i2c_wait?

Comment: the i2c wait function waites till all read or write processes are finished.